# Can "context" from HTTPS callable Cloud Functions be trusted?

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am using Cloud Functions to handle read/write to Cloud Firestore on the server side. The Cloud Functions are triggered by clients in the web app using HTTPS callable function.

When calling a Cloud Functions using HTTPS, there is a parameter sent from the client call "context" that carries user auth information. For example, a Cloud Functions on the server can look like this:

```
// Saves a message to the Firebase Realtime Database but sanitizes the text by removing swearwords.
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  // ...
});
```

However, since `context` is passed by the client, and the client could pass in a manipulated ID token, do I need to always perform a ID token verification before trusting and using something like `context.auth.uid` to interact with my database?

The ID token verification I am talking about is this:

```
// idToken comes from the client app
admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
  .then(function(decodedToken) {
    var uid = decodedToken.uid;
    // ...
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle error
  });
```

Essentially, I want to know if Firebase performs ID token verification automatically when passing `context` using https call and therefore I can go ahead and trust that if the client has manipulated `context`, the https call will fail due to token verification failing. Or, do I need to explicitly do a manual ID token verification on the server every single time to check the integrity of `context`, since the client can easily insert a manipulated token using the browser's devtools or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the ID token is automatically included in the request and verified in the function.  You don't have to write code to verify the toekn when using callable functions.

Comment: What happens when the client explicitly pass in a manipulated ID token when calling that HTTPS callable function, like `var addMessage = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('addMessage');
addMessage({text: messageText}, [MANIPULATED ID TOKEN]).then...`?

Comment: It should fail, since the (invalid) token can't be validated.

Comment: @DougStevenson What would be the response if the user has been disabled? Whether that request will reject or allowed?